# Can anyone please advise me where I'm going wrong with this binary search code? Unable to print index to user

Tags: python, algorithm, search

```
def binarySearch(list, selection):
  start = 0
  end = len(list) - 1

  while start <= end:
    middle = start + (end - start) // 2  
    middleValue = list[middle]
    if middleValue == selection:
      return middle
    elif selection < middleValue:
      end = middle - 1
    else:
      start = middle + 1

  return None

lista = [1, 5, 7, 10, 11, 19,]

print(lista)

selectiona = int(input('Enter a number to search for: '))
index = lista.index(selectiona)

binarySearch(lista, selectiona)


print(str(selectiona)) + "found at index " + str(index))

exit = input()
```

It works without printing the index, but this is a requirement. If anyone can advise me on what I'm doing wrong I'd be greatly appreciative. thanks

Comment: Questions still there buddy. Lockdown getting to you?

Answer (score 1):

In the line `print(str(selectiona)) + "found at index " + str(index))` your parentheses are wrong, you close one too many after `selectiona`. Try this instead:

`print(str(selectiona) + "found at index " + str(index))`

Additionally, the result of your binary search isn't what you're printing. Did you mean to do `index = binarySearch(lista, selectiona)` instead?

Comment: Thanks for replying!
I'm still very amateur so I can't fully gasp why the storing the index requires passing the function w/arguments rather than just the list, which wouldn't change in the progam.

Comment: @scopuli1 I'm not sure I'm understanding your followup question correctly. When you write `def binarySearch(list, selection):` you define `binarySearch` as a function that requires two arguments, _list_ and _selection_. When you call this function with `binarySearch(lista, selectiona)` you provide _lista_ and _selectiona_ as the concrete arguments to run this function with. This function returns the found position, and by prepending the call with `index = ` we store this result in the variable _index_ so we can print it later.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the `index` using python modules in the line `index = lista.index(selectiona)` and you are not using the output provides by the `binarySearch` function.

```
def binarySearch(list, selection):
  start = 0
  end = len(list) - 1

  while start <= end:
    middle = start + (end - start) / 2  
    middleValue = list[middle]
    if middleValue == selection:
      return middle
    elif selection < middleValue:
      end = middle - 1
    else:
      start = middle + 1

  return None

lista = [1, 5, 7, 10, 11, 19,]

print(lista)

selectiona = int(input('Enter a number to search for: '))

index = binarySearch(lista, selectiona)

if index:
    print(str(selectiona) + " found at index " + str(index))
else:
    print(str(selectiona) + " is not there in the list")

exit = input()
```

Comment: **Side note:** `middle = (start + end) // 2` can be done safely in Python.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Amazes me how someone can batter out this code in minutes and i've been stuck on it for hours!
I never though that I'd need to consider if the value wasn't found.
Can I ask, why do you need to pass the function with the arguments to find the index, and not just the list?

Comment: If you just pass the list as argument, the function doesn't know which number to search in that list, so it need the number which it needs to search.